# Email client for Linux which can store GPG messages decrypted

Tags: linux, email-client, gnupg

Is there any graphical email client for Linux which can store GPG messages decrypted? I have tried Thunderbird with Enigmail and Evolution but if I'm right none of them support this.

(I know that this is somehow a security hole. The mailbox would be on an encrypted drive.)

Comment: Never used a GUI email client that does that, but `mutt` [which is a CLI email client] has the `decrypt-copy` and `decrypt-move` commands doing just what you asked for

Comment: Would be great to have also the possibility to save every encrypted mail automatically decrypted (after typing in your password). Furthermore if you have thousands of encrypted mails on your drive it should be nice if you could save them all permamently decrypted just with one click.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/46580/5289

Comment: Here is a faq-entry about the enigmail-case: http://www.mozilla-enigmail.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=637&start=0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I never used a GUI email client which does that, you can use `mutt` [ which is a CLI email client ], and which has two useful commands:

- `decrypt-copy` -> Lets you save the decrypted contents of an email to a file
- `decrypt-save` -> Does a `decrypt-copy` then deletes the email

These two commands are unbound by default, but you can bind them with the [bind](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-3.html#ss3.3) command, e.g.:

```
bind pager <F5> decrypt-copy
bind pager <F6> decrypt-save
```

Would make <kbd>F5</kbd> do a `decrypt-copy` and <kbd>F6</kbd> do a `decrypt-save`

Answer (score 1):

KMail supposedly has a setting for this. However, [the documentation is ambiguous as to whether it actually works](http://userbase.kde.org/KMail/FAQs_Hints_and_Tips#Store_encrypted_mails_as_unencrypted):

> Symptom: You exchange encrypted mail with a friend, but would like to store it unencrypted, once you have opened the message.
>
> Solution: To store emails that have been decrypted once in unencrypted format henceforth, add this to your kmailrc configuration file, in the [Reader] section:
>
> ```
> store-displayed-messages-unencrypted=true
> ```
>
> This may only work with SMIME but implementation for OpenPgP is being worked on.

Answer (score 0):

Since you store the mailbox on an encrypted drive anyway, why not put a passwordless copy of your private key there as well and configure enigmail to use that one? That way you won't modify the original email and yet directly see it decrypted whenever needed.

Comment: A possible drawback of this method is that the mails will not necessarily searchable.

Comment: @student True, [here's the relevant enigmail bug report](http://sourceforge.net/p/enigmail/bugs/2/), which blames [this Thunderbird bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=188988)